# How do I append a string to a bash variable to return the value of another variable?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to get someone else's bash that sets various variables depending upon where a system comes up (z/VM Disaster Recovery provision). It is written so that it dots in a file containing variables with assigned values like this:

```
. /tmp/listofvars

IP=${SITE}IP
```

The value of the variable "$SITE" is set higher in the script, the result should be one of two things, either the value of the variable "$PRIP" for the production IP subnet value held in the variable list or the value of the variable "$DRIP" for the disaster recovery subnet value also held in the variable list that gets dotted in.

What actually happens is that the value of the $SITE variable gets concatenated to the string "IP" so the result is either "PRIP or "DRIP" depending on where I run the script. What I want is for the value of the $PRIP or $DRIP rather than the value of $SITE with the string 'IP' concatenated to it.

Comment: Associative arrays would be a better solution, IMO. But that would involve rewriting not just this script, but that listofvars file and any other script that uses listofvars file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use variable reference as:

```
echo "${!IP}"

# will print value of $PRIP if $IP=PRIP
```

Comment: +1 for the right approach; based on the OP's somewhat convoluted question my guess is that the specific answer sought is `IP=${!SITE}IP`.

Comment: I would like to add another way you will see is to use the eval command, but do not be tempted!  It's dangerous.  If the variable being eval'd can be manipulated into containing a command, eval will run it.